# define global variable with delegates

Tags: variables, delegates, global

Is it possible in Javascript to declare a global variable and populate in a delegate function?
I have a function that directs to a delegate function.  The problem is that global variables cannot be reference or populated in delegate functions.
In this example, userName is ALWAYS null.  Calling getUserInfo works and displays properly in an alert but the variable is never populated.

```
var userName = null;

function getUserInfo() 
{         
clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current()        
oWeb = clientContext.get_web();        
user = oWeb.get_currentUser();        
clientContext.load(user);        
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this,   this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));    
}     
function onQuerySucceeded() 
{        
    var message = "User Information";        
    message += "\n User Name: " + user.get_title();     
    userName = user.get_title();
    message += "\n Login Name: " + user.get_loginName();                   
}     
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) 
{        
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());    
}
```